# Indian leaving from nepal with a cancelled entry stamp

Tags: indian-citizens, passport-stamps, nepal

I entered by land and applied for an entry and exit stamp.

They gave me the stamp, then told me I don't need one and wrote cancelled through it.

I want to leave from kathmandu. I have an Indian passport with the cancelled entry stamp.

Is there a problem?

Comment: I’m probably missing something but I don’t fully understand the question. I believe Indian citizens can enter Nepal visa-free. A cancelled entry stamp can indicate a denial of entry, or an entry that wasn’t completed. How long have you been in Nepal? You mention an exit stamp but say your entry stamp was cancelled and you’re still there?

Comment: AFAIK Indian nationals can travel to/from Nepal without a passport too so I don't see any problem for you. They probably just cancelled the stamp because Indian nationals can't be given one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an entry stamp to enter Nepal since you're an indian citizen. The people checking your passport when exiting Nepal will know this and also know why the first stamp was cancelled (since it was invalid).

You could ask for a cancelled exit stamp though!